# Virtually cyclic groups: Is the finite permutation group virtually cyclic? & Uncountable groups cannot be virtually cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, cyclic-groups

I can't answer two questions about Virtually Cyclic Groups. Could anybody help me? I have already proven that the ininite dihedral group is virtually cyclic. I find the questions difficult because I can't think of counter examples or how to construct a subset that works.

A group is called virtually cyclic if there exists a cyclic subgroup of finite index.

1. Prove or disprove: $Sx$ (the group of permutations of a set $X$ with $f(x)\neq x$ for only finitely many $x\in X$) is virtually cyclic.
2. Show that an uncountable group cannot be virtually cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one:

No (if $X$ is infinite).  Suppose $S_X$ were virtually cyclic, with $<g>$ a cyclic group of finite index.  But then $G=<g>$ fixes all elements in $X$ outside of a finite set.  Since $X$ is infinite (by assumption) there is a countable set in $X^G$, $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.  But then no two of the transpositions $(x_{2i},x_{2i-1})$ define the same coset.

For the second:  just cardinality.  The cosets of $G$ cover group in question.  $G$ is countable and a finite union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain a bit more about your first proof? I don't really get the part where you introduce X^(G). What would the proof look like if X=N?

Comment: Sure.  $X^G$ is the set fixed by $G$.  That's got the same cardinality as $X$!  (since the generator $g$ fixes all but a finite list, so does all of $G$ so $X-X^G$ is finite.  Now take any two elements $x,y$ in $X^G$ and let $\tau_{x,y}$ be the transposition.  The coset $G\tau_{x,y}$ fixes every element in $X^G- \{x,y\}$.  Hence if you then take $\tau_{a,b}$ for two elements in$X^G-\{x,y\}$ it can't be in that coset.

Comment: Specializing to $\mathbb N$ doesn't change much.  Instead of $X^G$ you can write $\{n>N\}$ for suitably large $N$.  Might clarify things a bit.

Comment: To phrase things (slightly) differently:  Look at any coset of $G$.  It fixes all but finitely many elements of $X$.  Hence any finite collection of cosets also fixes all but finitely many elements of $X$.  But then we can always find a permutation outside all of those cosets.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. Use 2. and a sufficiently large $X$, for instance.
2. What is the largest possible cardinality of a cyclic (sub)group?